# "He'd so much as touched" meaning

Tags: meaning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“I so much as look” doesn't make any sense to me](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/62791/i-so-much-as-look-doesnt-make-any-sense-to-me)

I found the following in a book:

> Goyle reached toward the Chocolate Frogs next to Ron ---- Ron leapt forward, but before *he'd so much as touched* Goyle, Goyle let out a horrible yell.

I can't make sense of the part in italic. Could someone explain what it means and how is it constructed?

Comment: Have you checked [the dictionary definition](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/so_much_as)? Or searched the site to find [the answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/62791/i-so-much-as-look-doesnt-make-any-sense-to-me)? Because at 900+ rep you really should.

Comment: Dictionaries don't tell you when a phrase is a [Negative Polarity Item](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/NPIs.pdf) like _so/as much as V_, or a Negative Trigger like _if_. Nor what happens when an NPI occurs outside the scope of a trigger.

Answer (score 2):

`before he'd so much as touched Goyle` means that `before he could even touch Goyle`. You can understand the sentence as:

> Goyle reached toward the Chocolate Frogs next to Ron ---- Ron leapt forward, but ***before he could even touch*** Goyle, Goyle let out a horrible yell.